# barcode reader is not working after converting html to android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, barcode-scanner

I have created a application using `html,css` and `jquery`.From browser barcode scanner working fine.but when i convert my application to android using `PhoneGap` its input field not reading barcode scanner it's remains blank.

code sample:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" style="margin-top:10px">
<div>
  <label for="barcode"> Barcode:</label>
  <input type="text" id="barcode" name="barcode" data-mini="true" style="height:50px; font-size:20px">
</div>
```

after reading barcode i am moving to next page.

Comment: Have you tested the barcode scanner in a blank document? The web browser is looking for a keyboard input, so maybe you need to change your keyboard? Trying to think how to test this.

Comment: No, i have barcode that contains numbers.